# Scale path proportionally from centre without affecting type on path illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6

I have created text on a path. The text however does not fit. I don't want to make the text any smaller instead I want to extend the path evenly on both sides. I know with the path alone if I used the selection tool and shift+option it would scale proportionally from the centre I don't know how to do that however when there is type on that path as it will just scale the type.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I can't tell if the path is comprised of 2 or 3 anchors... 3 anchors may be possible.. 2 anchors are probably not possible)

Copy the object... 
Scale the copy to desired path size... 
Select type in original with the Type on a Path Tool...
Paste the type with the Type on a Path Tool to the scaled path.
Delete original object.

---

Alternatively, if you use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to select **only** the path. You must be certain *only* the path is selected.

You can then double-click the **Scale Tool** to scale only the path.

[image]

You *can* drag to scale if the **Bounding Box** (View menu) is on. After selecting *only the path*, hold the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> and you should see the bounding box for the path, still depressing the key you can click a handle and drag... adding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to keep it proportional.

[image]

I, personally, use the top copy/paste method. It's simply faster in most instances.